# Thread manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hello I recently started learning c# in Visual Studio..

I am trying to make a background process for my app.

I created a process and started it but I can't pause it without breaking my application.

```
public void WorkThreadFunction()
    {
    run = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string message = "\r\n"+i+" Running...";
            if (txtBox.InvokeRequired == true)
                txtBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { txtBox.Text += message; });
            else
                txtBox.Text += message;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(WorkThreadFunction);
        if (run == false)
        {
            btnCapture.Text = "Abort";
            lblStatus.Text = "Thread status: " + thread.ThreadState;
            thread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            btnCapture.Text = "Capture";
            lblStatus.Text = "Thread status: " + thread.ThreadState;
            //thread.Abort(); thread.Unset(); Thread.Sleep(999999); thread.WaitOne();
            txtBox.Text += "Work!";
        }
    }
```

Also thread.ThreadState always returns "Unstarted"...
I tried using "ManualResetEvent" but this just freezes my app...
Help? :S

Comment: Any reason you are using raw threads instead of Tasks?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, you check `ThreadState` before calling `Start()`, thus it's unstarted.

As an unrelated note, you don't need that `InvokeRequired` check, it's always required in this context.

Comment: Okay, but how to pause the process?

Comment: WorkThreadFunction (the counting) should be paused when clicked on the button second time....

Comment: Depends on what's inside the function, there's no catch-all solution. The only generic way of pausing execution of a thread is to register as a debugger for the process and freeze the thread as a debugger. In your instance, put a volatile boolean variable and in the `for` loop check it. `while(RequestPause);`